# how to use h2load to do benchmark for http2 server based on Netty?

Tags: netty, benchmarking, http2, nghttp2

When I use default `no-tls` protocol `h2c` of `h2load`, I find `netty` doesn't do upgrade because `h2load` doesn't send upgrade request. How can I do benchmark for **clear-text** `http2` benchmark for my `netty` `http2` server? Look forward to your reply.

This statement return `false` :

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerUpgradeHandler#isUpgradeRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

`io.netty.handler.codec.http2.CleartextHttp2ServerUpgradeHandler.PriorKnowledgeHandler` 
Peek inbound message to determine current connection wants to start HTTP/2 by HTTP upgrade or prior knowledge